# MotionLayout produces incorrect animation

Tags: android, android-animation, android-constraintlayout, android-motionlayout

I'm trying to make the [following screen](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/assets/7915327/80b3562d-c1e8-438c-89b0-f3043c28370b) with MotionLayout. Basically, it has an appbar, cover, user information and content. When the user swipes up, user info goes right under appbar, leaving only content view (green) and app bar.

It looks great and works in portrait mode. Doesn't require any code except XML. However, in landscape mode, it shows a different animation for the content view. It interpolates the size and position of content (green) from the upper left corner instead of being right under user info (red). The only differences however is that in landscape cover fill parent completely, though it's feels like it shouldn't the problem for MotionLayout to produce correct animation in this case.

[Here's the video](https://github.com/androidx/constraintlayout/assets/7915327/17464e84-bd70-4bd3-b994-480a974ff878) in landscape mode.

I want the animation in landscape mode to be the same as in portrait mode.
Is it a bug or am I doing something wrong?

Using `androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4`

Motion Layout:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/motion_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layoutDescription="@xml/scene2"
    tools:ignore="HardcodedText">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/cover"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="@color/vk_blue_200"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Image cover"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/header"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#FF0000"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="User info"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/content"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#00FF00"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:text="Content"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:background="#0000FF"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="AppBar"
        android:textColor="@color/white"
        android:textSize="16sp" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.motion.widget.MotionLayout>
```

Motion scene:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<MotionScene xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">

    <Transition
        app:constraintSetEnd="@+id/end_set"
        app:constraintSetStart="@+id/start_set">

        <OnSwipe app:dragDirection="dragUp" />

    </Transition>

    <ConstraintSet android:id="@+id/start_set">

        <!-- Image with ratio 2:1 (in portrait) or full screen (in landscape) -->

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/cover"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintDimensionRatio="H,2:1"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="-10dp"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/cover" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/header" />

    </ConstraintSet>

    <ConstraintSet
        android:id="@+id/end_set"
        app:deriveConstraintsFrom="@id/start_set">

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="60dp"
            android:visibility="visible"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

        <Constraint
            android:id="@+id/header"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="@id/toolbar"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent" />

    </ConstraintSet>

</MotionScene>
```

Comment: @id/cover is set to aspect ratio 2x1 and contrained to all sides. 
In Portrait mode  (given a 20x9  screen) you will have a region 9x4.5
In Landscape mode (20x9) you will have a 20x10  region(or 18x9). Covering most or all of the screen).
The header will be below that
The content will be below that. 
ConstraintLayout will not constraint things properly when they are compleatly off screen. 
I  see what it does in landscape but I have no idea what you wanted to happen.